# jQuery validation is loaded but doesnt display error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple site, which has a form and an inputbox. I want to validate weather or not this input box is filled, with jQuery validation. The validation plugin is loaded, but i dont get any error messages.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/euwPz/

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#FormName").validate();
  });
  </script>
```

this code in your ready function.

this will run the validation .

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck again your [link](http://jsfiddle.net/euwPz/1/) . Because you import only locale file, you also needed to import the plugin [file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js) then put this code to your ***$(document).ready***

```
$("#myForm").validate();
```